# Asp.net loginform on IE 11.0 on Windows 8.1 not working

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, authentication, redirect, windows-8.1

Our webapp login form has been in production for years now (11.000+ unique logins, 500.000+ in total) without ever failing. Now it seems that there is an issue with IE 11.0 on Windows 8.1 (win 8.0 seems to be ok)

The app is written in ASP.NET 4.0, auth mode is "Forms", running on Windows Server 2008.

After successful auth I do a redirect, like:

```
Response.Redirect("~/foo/bar.aspx", True)
```

All seems to work when running local (testet on browserstack).

I am unsure what more details I should supply to the question as I am totally confused on where the error lie.

The behavior can be seen on this test-page using this password: **M4DW25**
[https://app.jobmatchprofile.com/backend/login.aspx](https://app.jobmatchprofile.com/backend/login.aspx?loginerror=invalidpassword)

Gives below HTTP 400 errorpage  (note the missing second bullet - dont know if that means anything or its just Windows being sloppy):

[image]

Comment: It is working on Windows 8.1 using Firefox 24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved when updating the server with all pending Windows updates - so I guess this must have been fixed in one of MS .NET 4.0 updates.